# Website on different resolutions

Tags: html, css, resolution

I have a problem with my website. It looks great on my 20" screen but on the 11" it does not. The `#logo` is covering `#menu` and the `#bubble` appears beneath the `#frame`. As you see in the code, I have set up precentage size parameters because I found such a solution in a tutorial. It worked for many elements but not for all. What is the problem?

I believe this may be something to do with the `#bubble` height and width because it is still in `em`s. When I tried doing it with percentages, I lost the circular shape and the `#bubble` went to the bottom of the page often.

#### HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="top">
        <div>
            <p id="logo">XXXXXXXXXXX</p>

            <div id="menu">
                <h3 id="test">xxxxxx</h3>
                <h3 id="test2">xxxxxx</h3>
                <h3 id="test3">xxxxxx</h3>
                <h3 id="test4">xxxxx</h3>
                <h3 id="test5">xxxxxx</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="frame">
            <div id="main"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

#### CSS

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0%;
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-right: 0%;
    background-image: url("http://www.wallpapersmood.com/uploads/2010-07/july-high-defintion-wallpaper/1280109101-FWEMRDA.jpg");
}

#top {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

#logo {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 0.5%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    color: white;
    font-family: Impact,cursive;
    font-size: 160%;
}

h3 {
    width: 10%;
    height: 10%;
    border-radius:  9px;
    text-align:  center;
    line-height: 2;
    display: table-cell;
    font-size: 120%;
    font-family: "Verdana";
    color: white;
}

h3:hover {
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left bottom,
        left top,
        color-stop(0.35, rgb(60,156,196)),
        color-stop(0.68, rgb(90,188,236)),
        color-stop(0.84, rgb(117,226,255)));
    opacity: 1;
}

#menu {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-top: 0.5%;
}

#frame {
    width: 78%;
    height: 90%;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-top: 1%;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 0.9;
    float: right;
}

#main {
    height: 90%;
    width: 80%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius:15px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 2%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: auto;
}

#main img {
    max-width: 60%;
    max-height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 2%;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
#bubble {
    position: absolute;
    height: 14em;
    width: 14em;
    border: 6px dashed white;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-top: 1%;
    opacity: 0.6
}

#bubble p {
    position: relative; 
    top: 20%;
    font-size: 200%;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Impact";
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Makaveli! When you say that this feature "doesn't work", what exactly do you mean? There are a lot of different meanings for this. To help get your problem understood by other users, try adding a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to help.

Comment: "The #logo is covering #menu and the #bubble appears beneath the #frame."

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for *Responsive Design*.

Comment: Do all of the popular websites use this Responsive Design? As a Internet viewer I have never experienced any website having troubles on different resolutions. That's why I am puzzled with such big troubles while creating one.

Comment: Responsive design is a name for the process that makes a website look good a different resolutions. (The website "responds" to various device sizes.) This is usually accomplished through the use of CSS media queries which load different styles based screen resolution. Many major websites use this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CSS @media` queries to apply different styles for different screen sizes.
Read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Basically it's like `if` statements.. "if the window size is more than 500px" apply a certain set of `CSS` rules..  "if the window size is less than 500px and more than 300px" apply another set of rules etc..